# Filtering SQLite database with SearchBar

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

i´ve been able to generate and show a SQList database and now i wanna filter it with a Search Bar, i´ve been reading many tutorials, but i´m not able to make it work...

I have an SQLite Model with this code:

```
using SQLite;
namespace AppListo
{
public class Employee
  {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public long EmpId
    { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string EmpName
    { get; set; }

  }
}
```

...and i retrieve a datalist from the database with:

```
public List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        return dbConn.Query<Employee>("Select * From [Employee]");
    }
```

...and i show the list in a ContentPage with this xaml code:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstData" HasUnevenRows="false" Header="Header Value" Footer="Footer" ItemSelected="OnSelection" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5,5,5,5">
                            <Label Text="{Binding EmpName}" FontSize="Medium" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

...and this code behind:

```
var vList = App.DAUtil.GetAllEmployees();
lstData.ItemsSource = vList;
```

...but i don´t know how to filter this list with a searchbar.
Could you help me to achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a property on your `View Model` like

`public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }`

```
<ListView x:Name="lstData" HasUnevenRows="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" Header="Header Value" Footer="Footer" ItemSelected="OnSelection" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5,5,5,5">
                            <Label Text="{Binding EmpName}" FontSize="Medium" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then create a method to bind your `dataset` values to your list view

```
        private async Task BindEmployees()
        {


            List<Employee> employees = await GetAllEmployees();

            Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(

                            vList.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(mySearchString)).
                            OrderBy(x => x.EmpName).ToList());

            await RaisePropertyChanged("Employees");


        }
```

Call this method on page load or inside your `View Model's` constructor

```
            Task.Run(async() => {
                await BindEmployees();
            });
```

Also, create a Handler method which will be called every time your enter any thing on `search bar`

and again call `BindEmployees` method inside that handler function

```
 FilterEmployee_Handler(TextChangedEventArgs args) {
await BindEmployees(),

}
```

Answer (score 2):

use LINQ

```
var vList = App.DAUtil.GetAllEmployees();
lstData.ItemsSource = vList.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(mySearchString));
```

Comment: Beware of null values for the search pattern. Also, the Contains is case-sensitive, so have that in mind too.